# getting bootstrap's css into existing site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sprockets

I am having problems getting Bootstrap into an existing site. I do the following:

in Gemfile (already have: `gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'`):
add

```
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.0.0'
```

at cli:

```
bundle install
```

in application.css add to the top:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

in application.js (this part works fine), add

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
```

restart Webrick

in layout, all the javascript is there (compilation occurs in development.log); none of the css is there.

What am I doing wrong? Or what should I look at next? Should I be seeing the bootstrap files /app/assets/stylesheets?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

application.css needed to be application.css.scss

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to add in **config.rb**:

```
require 'bootstrap-sass'
compass install bootstrap
```

source: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass#existing-project